# How do you show an alert box (in PHP) just before reloading a page or redirecting it to another page

Tags: php, redirect, alert

> I have this code right here which attempts to show an alert dialog box once a row is successfully inserted into the database. Also I want to reload the page after displaying the dialog box. It successfully pops up an alert box when commented out the `header("location: link-1.php?e=Changes has been saved.")`, but when I uncomment it, the dialog doesn't show up anymore.

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 1){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updated successfully.');</script>";
    header("location: link-1.php?e=Changes has been saved.");
}
else {
    header("location: link-1.php?error=Something went wrong.");   
}
```

Comment: PHP Can't show an alert. It doesn't run in the browser. If you need to display an alert _before_ reloading a page, you have to do that on the page in Javascript. The php will not run until the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to show an alert and reload the page:

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 1)
{
?>
  <script>
    alert('Updated successfully');
    location.reload();  // It will reload the page and reloading will get the latest inserted data from db
  </script>
<?php    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call PHP Header to redirect since by sending out your html (javascript) your Header has already been sent. You need to redirect using javascript.  `window.location.href={your_url}` will redirect.

But I don't think this is the right approach, you should probably do it backwards. Do the logic on redirect in PHP first, then on that script include your logic to whether show the alert box.